# Aplicar classe quando for segundo item da listagem

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
<ul class="grid_1330 margin-auto">
  <li class="homeListagemLi">
    <div class="homeListagemDiv">
       <ul>
         <li><img src="./imagens/pessoa.jpg" height="220" width="220" /></li>
         <li><span>teste1</span></li>
         <li><span>teste2</span></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Assim está meu CSS:

```
.homeListagemDiv>ul>li>img{width: 220px;height: 220px;}
.homeListagemDiv>ul>li>span{
    color: #00aeef;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "open_sansbold";<sp
}
```

Eu quero que quando, o `span` seja o segundo, ali dentro da LI, ele aceite outra formatação, diferente da que coloquei no CSS. Claro, eu poderia criar uma classe e colocar na `li`, mas, tem outra forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem o que você quer que é esse elemento

```
   <ul>
     <li><span>teste1</span></li>
     <li><span class="esse">teste2</span></li>
   </ul>
```

E não assim

```
   <ul>
     <li><span>teste1</span><span class="esse">teste1</span></li>
     <li><span>teste2</span></li>
    </ul>
```

Não da pra fazer só com css, no caso o segundo exemplo seria assim:

```
ul > li > span:nth-child(2) { color: red }
```

O que da pra fazer é pegar o segundo li, se o span ficar sempre ali

```
ul > li:nth-child(2) > span { color: red }
```

Comment: Isso Rodrigo. Eu quero que a palavra teste2, tenha atributos diferentes, porém não queria criar outra classe para isso, gostaria de saber se da pra reaproveitar.

Comment: Da sim @felipestoker, o segundo exemplo que eu dei funciona no seu caso, o que você não consegue fazer é pegar o segundo span que aparece "solto" ali dentro da ul.